# FFmpeg - Take 128 Channel WAV and Transcode to MKV with 128 Discrete Mono Tracks

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a use case where I need to take individual WAV files with 128 channels in each one and output corresponding MKVs with each source channel as its own discrete mono track.

I've been playing around with the channelsplit and channelmap functions but am having a hard time finding parameters that work with this many channels / this specific use case.

Is this even possible with FFmpeg?

So far I've mostly been trying different variations of:

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -filter_complex channelsplit out.mkv
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Identical question posted under another name in [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/36765/ffmpeg-take-128-channel-wav-and-transcode-to-mkv-with-128-discrete-mono-tracks) See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)